# Adobe PDF Form submitted but Request.Form collection is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I created a PDF form containing a textbox and a submit button. Users may open the PDF file in Adobe Acrobat Reader or in browser. After filling in the textbox and click on the submit button, an asp.net generic handler will process the submitted data.

But the problem I'm having now is that there is no submitted form data.

The PDF form submit button is setup as follow:
[image]

and the server side code:

```
public class PdfFormHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.RequestType == "POST")
        {
            var name = context.Request.Form["txtName"]; // <-- name is null. why?
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

the `context.Request.Form` collection is empty. Where does the `txtName` form element go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this myself. the problem is that I need to change the `Export Format` to `HTML`.

[image]